# Downloaded themes don't show up in Unity Tweak

Tags: themes, 16.04, unity-tweak-tool

I have a fresh 16.04 install, and try to customize it a bit.

I got a few themes in `/usr/share/themes`, but they are not listed in Unity Tweak. So I cannot try them.

Why is that ? How can I use them ?

[Themes aren't listed in Unity Tweak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn7F6.png)

They were already in that folder right after the installation, I only downloaded "Aurora".
As you can see on the picture, I can only access "Ambiance", "Highcontrast" and "Radiance".

Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

Try this [download](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3AHorst3180&package=arc-theme) to install  the ARC theme, it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I am quite happy with Arc-dark, but is there a more general solution ?